# Why are bones sticking out in Blender?

Tags: bones

I am exporting a model from DAZ3D as an fbx. In DAZ, the bone orientation looks perfectly fine:

[image]

When I import the FBX in Blender, the bones are sticking out.
[image]

Why is that so, and how could I get it to look like in DAZ3D?

Thank you.

Comment: In the FBX importer window there is an "Armature" tab in the right-side. You can adjust the bone rotation under it.

Comment: @FFeller Thank you. When I use "Automatic Bone Orientation", it gets *better*, but still not right. Perhaps a bug? I will file a bug report as I don't see any other way to get it right.

Comment: Probably not a bug, because most of the imported bones are rotated with 90°. For example Unreal Engine's rigs. The softwares have different coordinate system. Other rig's bones appears correctly like Mixamo characters.